# Spring security takes time to reload updated user credentials

Tags: spring, spring-security

From what I've been able to understand, Spring Security does not create a `UserCache` by default unless you explicitly do, so I don't understand why changing user credentials does not immediately invalidate the previous ones. Or a deleted user continues to be valid until some time has passed.

It should be added here that I am not overriding any of Spring Security's functionality. I'm not using RememberMe or making any effort to maintain sessions. I'm using basic authentication and I'm using database crud functions to update `UserDetails`, which maybe causing the issue here.

What I would like to know is:

- What is causing the delay here?
- Is overriding some functionality, like almost all answers refer to, the only way around it?